AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Areas_Admin_Views_Product_Add.ExecuteAsync() in Add.cshtml
enter image description here
enter image description here
Web Errro Page
enter image description here
Hello, even though the information is correct, I am getting a NullReferenceException error.
The project is also installed on my Github account, can you help?
@kutluali
I disabled the controlled structure in the products, but it still does not load. I also canceled the image upload.
AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Areas_Admin_Views_Product_Add.ExecuteAsync() in Add.cshtml
